# How to customize table role (privilege ) with another named (profil) that it already exist in database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a full-stack application (spring-boot,reactjs) with an existed database and entities, the problem that i'm facing is about spring security integration precisely **User** and **Role** entities which in my case i have to work with (**employee** and **profil**), even when i call **@PreAuthorize("hasProfil('Admin')")** the runtime ignore it it because that supposed to be **@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")**, How to make spring security work with employee and profil instead of user and role ?

*This the class that it supposed to be the user class:*

```
 public class Employe implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @Column(unique=true, nullable=false, precision=6)
        private Long id;
        @JsonIgnore
        @Column(precision=6)
        private BigDecimal cv;
        @Column(length=254)
        private String nom;
        @Column(length=254)
        private String prenom;
        @JsonIgnore
        @Column(length=254)
        private String login;
        @JsonIgnore
        @Column(length=254)
        private String mp;
        @JsonIgnore
        @Column(length=254)
        private String mail;
       @ManyToOne(optional=false)
       @JoinColumn(name="pro_id", nullable=false)
       private Profil profil;
```

*this is the Profil class that it supposed to be the class Role:*

```
public class Profil implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Size(max = 254)
    @Column(length = 254)
    private String libelle;
    @Size(max = 254)
    @Column(length = 254)
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "lock_flag")
    private Integer lockFlag;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profil")
    private Collection<Employe> employeCollection;

    public Profil() {
    }

    public Profil(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Integer getLockFlag() {
        return lockFlag;
    }

    public void setLockFlag(Integer lockFlag) {
        this.lockFlag = lockFlag;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Employe> getEmployeCollection() {
        return employeCollection;
    }

    public void setEmployeCollection(Collection<Employe> employeCollection) {
        this.employeCollection = employeCollection;
    }
```

*this is the the methode create which return UserDetails:*

```
  public static UserPrincipal create(Employe user) {
        Profil p = user.getProfil();
        Set<Profil> listProfil= new HashSet<>();
        listProfil.add(p);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = listProfil.stream().map(role ->
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getLibelle())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new UserPrincipal(
              user.getId(),
              user.getNom(),
              user.getPrenom(),
              user.getNumCin(),
              user.getLogin(),
              user.getMail(),
              user.getMp(),
              user.getTelephone(),
              authorities
        );
    }
```

*Class CustomUserDetailsService:*

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    EmployeRepository employeRepository; 
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String loginOrEmail) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // Let people login with either username or email

        Employe user = employeRepository.findByLoginOrMail(loginOrEmail, loginOrEmail).orElseThrow(() -> {
            logger.error("Utilisateur non trouvé");
            return new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username or email : " + loginOrEmail);
        });

        return UserPrincipal.create(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserById(Long id) {
        Employe user = employeRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundExceptionn("User", "id", id));

        return UserPrincipal.create(user);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the name of the expression? You use your classes for user and roles, that works. Just use `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")`.